# Secure Logic Apps with Http Trigger by only allowing Action Groups to Invoke

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an action group which is pointed to an Azure Logic App with an Http trigger. Is there a way to make it so the Http trigger can only be invoked by an action group? Preferably an action group in my subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http triggers are generated with a SAS(shared access signatures) key [Secure access in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app) by default. So in a sense it is secure by default.

The deployment will generate a url with a `sp` `sv` and a `sig`

//updated

You can set the Logic Apps Workflow settings to allow from only specific URLs or Only other logic apps.

[image: Workflow settings]

Using API management you could secure it with OAuth as an example.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, its a little disappointing that these have to have publicly accessible dns records by default. It would be nice if there was an option to have the logic app only accessible by Azure resources within your subscription.

Comment: @user1951756 I wasn't happy with my answer, went back and looked a bit more but yeah, I guess you could at least make it so only other logic apps could call the Logic App with an HTTP trigger? That's what I will be using as a default from now on, TIL, now I only have to find a ARM deployment parameter for it :)